# Determining if a number is negative in Scheme with one function

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

I have been going through The Little Schemer and I started getting curious about how to deal with negative numbers.  It seemed like a nice challenge to figure out how to build a function to determine if a number is negative or positive.

So far I have this solution:

```
(define negative?
  (lambda (a)
    (cond
      ((zero? a) #f)
      (else (negativeHelper (sub1 a) (add1 a))))))

(define negativeHelper
  (lambda (a b)
    (cond
      ((zero? a) #f)
      ((zero? b) #t)
      (else (negativeHelper (sub1 a) (add1 b))))))
```

This looks to be working nicely, but my question is if it is possible to right `negative?` without the helper function?

Comment: Why not just, y’know, check if the number is less than zero? `(define (negative? n) (< n 0))`

Comment: Actually the reason I wanted to determine if a number was negative was to write a < comparison function that worked with negative numbers.  In the spirit of the book which writes a number of functions from nearly scratch I wanted to keep trying.

Comment: You can simplify your first procedure to `(define negative?  (lambda (a) (negativeHelper a a)))`, and `negativeHelper` could be an inner procedure to `negative? `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but there's absolutely nothing wrong with the "helper" function.

You might like nesting inside the `negative?` function tho

```
(define (negative? x)
  (define (aux a b)
    (cond ((zero? a) #f)
          ((zero? b) #t)
          (else (aux (sub1 a) (add1 b)))))
  (aux x x))
```

Verify results

```
(negative? 4)  ; => #f
(negative? -4) ; => #t
(negative? 0)  ; => #f
```